# How to change the color of the text next to an input field in an HTML form?

Tags: html, forms, css

How can I change the color of the text next to an input field in an HTML form? The website I am working with has a dark background, and I want to change the text next to each input field to a different color; most likely white. How can I do this?

I hope that I don't seem too stupid asking this question. I am new to HTML and CSS, and have not had much practice.

Here is my HTML. I want the "first Name:" and other text like it to be a different color is all.

```
<form action="MAILTO:...........com" method="post" enctype="text/plain">
    First Name:
    <input type="text" name="firstname" placeholder="First">
    Last Name:
    <input type="text" name="lastname" placeholder="Last"><br><br>
    e-Mail:
    <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="example@example.com">
    Phone Number:
    <input type="text" name="phonenumber" placeholder="000-000-0000"><br><br><!--Change this to use the "tel" type when more browsers start supporting it-->
    Message:<br>
    <textarea name="message" placeholder="What would you like to say?" style="width: 100%; height: 200px;"></textarea><br><br>
    <div class="centeredsubmit">
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </div>
</form>
```

Also, how do I make it actually send the form to an email? I tried what I have above with my email, but it didn't ever come.

Thank you,
Matt

Comment: Can you post your HTML?

Comment: Hello Republican31. A democrat has a few questions for you... Do you have a style.css file?

Comment: I am sorry if my username offends you. I do have a CSS file, named main.css. I don't know what I need to put in the css file to make this happen. And I can not post my HTML at this time, but I can soon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`<div style="color:#ffffff;">`Your text next to your form.

```
</div>
```

Comment: Actually, not. It works fine if I put the whole form in the div, but then the text typed into the inputs the same color, so they are not visible. If I place it around the individual text, then it put it on a separate line. I don't know what to do.

Comment: I did a little experimenting, and made it work right by adding "display: inline-block;" to each of those styles. Thank you all for your help! Just one more thing: how can I make it send directly to email? I did a mailto link, but then it pulls up the email client and it just looks weird and unprofessional. I have heard that this requires JS and PHP to do. Can anyone show me exactly how?